# express: command not found , has worked before?

Tags: node.js, macos, express, terminal

I'm working on a OSX 10.10.4, I have worked with node.js and express before on this computer. 
But now when I want to start a new application, the computer won't recognize the command `express` anymore.

I've tried installing it with all these commands:

```
- npm install express
 - npm install -g express
 - npm install express -g
 - sudo npm install -g express
 - sudo npm install express -g
 - npm install express-generator
 - npm install -g express-generator
 - npm install express-generator -g
 - sudo npm install -g express-generator
 - sudo install express-generator -g
 - sudo npm install -g express-generator@3
 - sudo npm install -g express-generator@4
```

But it still doesn't recognize the command `express`

This is the output when I install without the `-g`

```
npm install express
express@4.13.3 node_modules/express
├── escape-html@1.0.2
├── merge-descriptors@1.0.0
├── cookie@0.1.3
├── array-flatten@1.1.1
├── utils-merge@1.0.0
├── cookie-signature@1.0.6
├── methods@1.1.1
├── fresh@0.3.0
├── range-parser@1.0.2
├── vary@1.0.1
├── path-to-regexp@0.1.7
├── content-type@1.0.1
├── etag@1.7.0
├── parseurl@1.3.0
├── content-disposition@0.5.0
├── serve-static@1.10.0
├── depd@1.0.1
├── qs@4.0.0
├── finalhandler@0.4.0 (unpipe@1.0.0)
├── on-finished@2.3.0 (ee-first@1.1.1)
├── debug@2.2.0 (ms@0.7.1)
├── proxy-addr@1.0.8 (forwarded@0.1.0, ipaddr.js@1.0.1)
├── type-is@1.6.6 (media-typer@0.3.0, mime-types@2.1.4)
├── accepts@1.2.12 (negotiator@0.5.3, mime-types@2.1.4)
└── send@0.13.0 (destroy@1.0.3, statuses@1.2.1, ms@0.7.1, mime@1.3.4, http-errors@1.3.1)
```

and when I install with the -g

```
sudo npm install -g express-generator
Password:
/Users/Maiteh/.node/bin/express -> /Users/Maiteh/.node/lib/node_modules/express-generator/bin/express
express-generator@4.13.1 /Users/Maiteh/.node/lib/node_modules/express-generator
├── sorted-object@1.0.0
├── commander@2.7.1 (graceful-readlink@1.0.1)
└── mkdirp@0.5.1 (minimist@0.0.8)
```

I have tried some other stuff like the `PATH` and `nodejs-legacy`, but none of them work.
With the `sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy` the computer doesn't find the command `apt-get`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's kind of a mishmash of problems you're describing here, so I'll try to address them one at a time.

1. Express is a popular framework for node.js.  The typical way to add it to your project is to do `npm install --save express` and then it will save it into your `package.json` file and install it into `node_modules`.  Adding `-g` to that command would attempt to install it globally, but that's not how express is used.  Express is used on a per-project basis.  See their [website](http://expressjs.com/) for details.
2. In the big list of commands you've run, you mention `express-generator`.  Express-generator is a tool that lets you quickly build out some boilerplate to make starting an express project a bit easier.  Since `express-generator` is meant to be run globally and not inside a project, you DO install it with the `-g` flag.  See their [website](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-generator) for details on use and installation.
3. You're trying to install some more node stuff with the `apt-get` command.  That command is used for package management on Linux (typically Ubuntu/Debian) machines.  Mac OS X doesn't come with it (and you absolutely don't need it).  Any instructions that mention running `apt-get` are not targeted towards Mac users.

Essentially, I don't think you have a problem, the logs you show are exactly what I'd expect to see.  Generate a boilerplate project with `express-generator` and you should be all set to start working on your express project.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your response, I was (and still am) kind of desperate because I can't seem to get it to work and I really suck at Node.js.
So I was really trying everything to get it to work, even the solutions on the pages for linux computers so it seems.

But I've tried the npm install --save express, it gave almost the exact same output as before (no errors) but the terminal still doesn't find the command express :s

Comment: That's what I was saying in my answer, there ISN'T an express command.  There isn't supposed to be.  You don't use it like that.

Comment: I'm sorry if I sound completely stupid now but then how do you create an express app where it automatically generates a bunch of files like the package.json file, app.js file , views folder ect. [Like this](https://gyazo.com/2e025b3c614a8bd1348b1f0d9779ab3d)

Comment: You don't sound stupid, it is rather confusing.  You should run `sudo npm install -g express-generator`, and see if it installs correctly.  If it does, running `express` as shown on the express-generator website should prompt you to create a project.  If this and my answer help you, please remember to mark it accepted.

Comment: That's exactly what I've tried to do, i do get a folder with node modules and inside a folder express but I can't run express

Comment: I sent you a request on Google hangouts, that might be easier than this.

Answer (score 6):

The reason I got `express:command not found` after I installed was because my `$PATH` didn't know where express was.

To anyone wanting to install the express command line tools I did this

`sudo npm install express-generator -g`

which resulted in

```
/usr/local/share/npm/bin/express -> /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/express-generator/bin/express
express-generator@4.13.1 /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/express-generator
├── sorted-object@1.0.0
├── commander@2.7.1 (graceful-readlink@1.0.1)
└── mkdirp@0.5.1 (minimist@0.0.8)
```

when I tried `express --version` I got a `command not found`

Open your bash_profile from terminal with `open ~/.bash_profile`

After that add the path you got after you installed express, in my case it was 
`/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/express-generator/bin/express`

Add this to your bash_profile

`export PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/express-generator/bin:$PATH`

Save the file and go back to terminal. Enter `hash -r` and then quit terminal and start it again.

Now if you try `express --version` for example you should see that the command line tools are working.